# uncrustify: how to combine arguments of multiline C function call on to a single line?

Tags: c++, c, function-call, uncrustify

I am using uncrustify 0.69.0 (I can't get 0.71.0 to compile yet). I have the following:

```
sendto(cmd_sock, buf, strlen(buf),
                0, (struct sockaddr *)&fromCmd,
                sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
```

And I want uncrustify to combine them to a single line:

```
sendto(cmd_sock, buf, strlen(buf), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&fromCmd, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
```

This old 2012 question is similar but existed during a much older version of uncrustify and did not have a solution:
[Uncrustify Collapse Multiline Function Call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12276328/uncrustify-colapse-multiline-function-call)
Is there a solution today?

2020-07-27- I tried to make a comment but it limited me to mostly nothing of value. So I'm updating my original question....
strange- nl_func_call_args is not found in my config files.... but this is:

```
# Whether to add a newline after each ',' in a function call if '(' and ')'
# are in different lines.
nl_func_call_args_multi_line    = false    # true/false
```

Notice that the options dont allow to "delete".  Doing a search in all the config files I have back to .67 does not find nl_func_call_args. if one removes any .uncrustify.cfg and runs uncrustify --update-config one will NOT find nl_func_call_args. When I get a new version of uncrustify I ALWAYS run a default and analyze what changed. This is the only way I can trust the configs. My original question still stands. This is about creating a standard for C code. I see a LOT of crazy function call formatting, especially in recent years. The only way to get it into shape is to FIRST remove all the multiline crap. Then I can edit if needed to a better format. Otherwise I'm editing EVERY STINKING line. For the record I have been writing C since 1981 and almost 100% adhere to K&R. I have a handful of deviations. I also use VI so ALL of the format features that were in the original VI I still want code to adhere to so this editor will work properly.
regards
oldunixguy

Comment: Isn't this going to make the code harder to read by blowing out the margins?

Comment: Have you tried deleting the newlines?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews - I think they are looking to have the reformatter do that automatically; I take the question to be a general reformatting rule, not how to manually edit one line.

Comment: Is there any reason for making it one line?  It doesn't affect the performance of the code.  Does not affect compilation or build speed.  The amount of file size saved is negligible.

Comment: Reformatting code is strictly about readability and enforcing a common style, not performance.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Add or remove newline after each ',' in a function call.
nl_func_call_args               = remove   # ignore/add/remove/force
```

That option was introduced on 2016-06-27 (796b5ba5)

Comment: strange.... not found in my config files.... but this is: 
# Whether to add a newline after each ',' in a function call if '(' and ')'
# are in different lines.
nl_func_call_args_multi_line    = false    # true/false